# Python Inherit one Class from two classes before (MachineLearning Preprocessing)

Tags: python, class, machine-learning

I am trying to write three classes .

First class is to separate the data in X_train,X_test etc.

Second Class gives me the statistical plots

Third Class is the pipeline class.

-> I will initialize the third class and want to get all the results of the classes.

I tried with runtests and FeatureUnion as multiple Pipelines but it didn't  work

```
class data:

    def __init__(self,data,target,runtests=True):
        self.data = data
        self.target= target
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.y_test = y_test

    def xy(self,data,target):
        self.X = data.drop([target])
        self.y = data.target

        return self.X,self.y

    def split_data(self):

        X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.drop(labels=['SalePrice'],axis=1),
                                                                       data.SalePrice,
                                                                       test_size=0.3,
                                                                       random_state=0)

        return self.X_train,self.X_test,self.y_train,self.y_test

class plot(data):

    def __init__(self,runtests=True):
        self.data = self.data
        self.X = self.X
        self.y = self.y
        self.target = self.target
        if runtests:
            self.describe_data(data)
            self.missing_values(data)
            self.plot_target_distribution(y)
            self.plot_target_distr_logtrans(y)
            self.feat_relevance_shap(X,y)
            self.corr(data,target)

    def describe_data(self,data):
        print(data.describe())


    def missing_values(self,data):

        print(mis_val_table_ren_columns)

    def plot_target_distribution(self):

       ......
        plt.show()

    def plot_target_distr_logtrans(self):
        ........
        plt.show()

    def corr(self):
        plt.show()

class pipe(plot):

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.y_test = y_test

    def pipeline(self):
        .......

        return train,test

        super().pipeline()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "*it didn't work*" is hardly informative for anyone willing to help; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `__init__()`s of `data` and `plot` are not being called.  It's entirely your responsibility to call the inherited methods when you override them in a subclass.